# Как исправить проблему с кириллицей в PdfTk при заполнении Pdf форм?

Tags: php, pdf, кириллица

Для заполнения pdf форм я изпользую библиотеку [mikeheartl](https://github.com/mikehaertl/php-pdftk), очень простая библиотека и все прекрасно работает, до того момента как мы начинаем заполнять форму кириллицей. Кириллица отображается только тогда, когда мы не выключаем редактирование полей, а мне нужно что бы редактирование было выключено и отображалась кириллица.

Тут конечно же проблема не в библиотеке а в самом pdftk, прочитал много таких же вопросов и тд. но они либо старые, либо там никто к конечной точке так и не пришел.

Может кто-то сталкивался с такой же проблемой и решил ее, или же нашел обход, буду рад если поможете.

Вот метод который я использую для генирации pdf файла.

```
private function generate($fields, $filename, $path)
{
    $options = array(
        'command' => "C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtk\bin\pdftk.exe",
        'useExec' => true,
    );

    $pdf = new Pdf($path, $options );
    $res = $pdf->fillForm($fields)
    ->flatten() // Отключает редактирование
    ->compress()
    ->needAppearances() 
    ->saveAs("./completed/" . $filename);
     

    if($res === false) {
        print_r($pdf->getError());
        return false;
    }

    return $filename;
}
```

P.s. за ошибки извиняюсь, пишу не своим родным языком.

Comment: противоречивое предложение - "Кириллица отображается только тогда, когда мы выключаем редактирование полей, а мне нужно что бы редактирование было выключено и отображалась кириллица."

Comment: ошибся, кириллица отображается только тогда, когда мы  не выключаем редактирование*